# How do I click on radio button with dynamic input using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-java

I want to be able to click on either "Male" or "Female" option by inputing the value through a parameter

```
public void enter_gender_as(String gender) {

       
WebElement g = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=(gender)]"));
g.click();
}
```

[HTML snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V95i8.png)

Comment: If one of these answers helped you, please select one.

Answer (score 1):

method:

```
public static void selectRadioButtonByValue(List<WebElement> radioButtons, String value) {
    for (WebElement radioButton: radioButtons) {
        if (radioButton.getAttribute("value").toLowerCase().equals(value.toLowerCase())) {
            radioButton.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
List<WebElement> radioButtons = driver.findElements(By.id("gender"));
selectRadioButtonByValue(radioButtons, "male");
```

optionaly with `WebDriver driver` as argument:

```
public static void selectRadioButtonByValue(WebDriver driver, List<WebElement> radioButtons, String value) {
    for (WebElement radioButton: radioButtons) {
        if (radioButton.getAttribute("value").toLowerCase().equals(value.toLowerCase())) {
            radioButton.click();
            break;
        }
    }
}

selectRadioButtonByValue(driver, radioButtons, "male");
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got it, just write your code like this:

```
public void enter_gender_as(String gender) {
WebElement g = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=(" + gender + ")]"));
g.click();
}
```

Then call it correctly:

```
enter_gender_as("Male");
```

If you wanna get fancy then you can put `if`s to check if the value isn't `Male` or `Female`. You can make `gender` `.toLowerCase()`. And you can add in an explicit wait, like an `ExpectedCondition` to wait for element to load. But this is the base functionality.
Here's an example of what the "fancy" one would look like:

```
public void enter_gender_as(String gender) {
if(!gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Male") && !gender.equalsIgnoreCase("Female")){
System.out.println("Not a valid value! Please enter Male or Female");
}
WebElement g = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=(" + gender.toLowerCase + ")]"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, [int for timeout]).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(g));

g.click();
}
```

Comment: `.equalsIgnoreCase` I didn't know. One learns every day :-)

Comment: I know right? I love that feeling of finding a new method! Glad I was able to help show you something new!